# If $E$ is countable and $\mathcal{E} = 2^{E}$, then every numerical function on $E$ is $\mathcal{E}$-measurable

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, measurable-functions

My question is on Exercise 2.24 (page 12) of *Probability and Stochastics* by Erhan Cinlar:

> 2.24 *Discrete spaces*. Suppose that $E$ is countable and $\mathcal{E} = 2^E$, the discrete $\sigma$-algebra on $E$. Then $(E,\mathcal{E})$ is said to be *discrete*. Show that every [numerical] function on $E$ is $\mathcal{E}$-measurable.

I'm unsure about my argument because it is suspiciously simple and it doesn't use the fact that $E$ is countable:

**"Proof"**: Let $f: E \rightarrow \overline{\mathbb{R}}$ and let $B \in \mathcal{B}(\overline{\mathbb{R}})$ (the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on  $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$). Then $f^{-1}(B)$ is obviously a subset of $E$. But $2^E$ is (by definition) the collection of *all* subsets of $E$, so $f^{-1}(B) \in 2^E$. Thus, $f$ is $\mathcal{E}$-measurable.

Am I missing something, or is the assumption that $E$ is countable irrelevant?

Comment: That's all is needed.

Comment: I don't think countability matters here.  If you have the discrete $\sigma$-algebra on a space, then every function will be measurable, by your argument.